# How can I install mcrypt under PHP7? Laravel needs it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-7, mcrypt

Since Laravel4 requires `mcrypt` extension, and PHP7 doesn't seem to have `mcrypt` extension, is there any workaround for this to work?

Comment: You've tagged this Laravel 5.1, which is the newest version of Laravel. It does not require mcrypt to work. See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation for reference of what you need.

Comment: You could install it? Usually that's the workaround when you're missing a library

Comment: @JoelHinz I changed the to Laravel 4.

Comment: @DamienPirsy Thanks, I will try installing it manually.

Comment: if you're on centos https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 85):

Had the same issue - PHP7 missing mcrypt.

This worked for me. When asked, keep local PHP configuration files.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Restart FPM (or Apache or NGINX etc.) after installation.

Comment: I had to do this first `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Comment: @user985366 thanks ...yes we have to do this `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` and then `sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt
sudo apt-get upgrade` and then it worked for me

Comment: @Ryderpro Do we need to install `mcrypt` when we're already getting `php7.0-mcrypt`? Or are they 2 diff things entirely?

Answer (score 29):

I'm on Mac and with laravel valet I've solved with this:

> brew install php70-mcrypt

Answer (score 13):

Even if you enable mcrypt in php.ini, this issue may occur.
Try the following steps.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt
```

I am working in ubuntu 16.04 and the following commands also helped me.

```
whereis php  -shows the files with this name
php -v   -shows the php version
which php -shows current php version that is running on the server
```

Answer (score 8):

On ubuntu: According to [launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php7.0) the package for mcrypt is called php7.0-mcrypt.

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt` to install

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal with Ctrl + Alt + T and run following commands for PHP7.0 on Ubuntu 16.4

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

php7 have mcrypt, you can enable it in php.ini and then everything will work fine.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I install `PHP7 Mcrypt`?
I tried to find if `PHP7` has any `Mcrypt` extension, but to no avail. 
`PHP5` had `Mcrypt` as `php5-mcrypt` which can be enabled and disabled easily with `php5enmod` and `php5dismod` respectively.

Comment: In /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini you have to check that the extension is enabled:
extension=mcrypt.so
and not ;extension=mcrypt.so

Answer (score 2):

do like this:

1. `wget http://jp2.php.net/distributions/php-7.0.3.tar.gz`
2. `tar zxf php-7.0.3.tar.gz`
3. `cd php-7.0.3/ext/mcrypt`
4. `/php7-path/bin/phpize` (when error such as `configure: error: mcrypt.h not found. Please reinstall libmcrypt` run `apt-get install libmcrypt-dev`)
5. `./configure --with-php-config=/php7-path/bin/php-config`
6. `(sudo) make && make install` .this will install the mcrypt.so in `php-7.0.3/ext/mcrypt/modules`
7. cp to the `/usr/lib/php/20151012/` what is the shared extensions dir
8. create a mcrypt.ini in `/etc/php/mods-available/` write as `extension=mcrypt.so`
9. create link to this such as `sudo ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/mcrypt.ini 20-mcrypt.ini` in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d`
10. create link to this such as `sudo ln -s /etc/php/mods-available/mcrypt.ini 20-mcrypt.ini` in `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d`
11. `sudo service nginx restart`
12. `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`
13. yes it is.

Comment: This worked for me when the ppa for installation via apt-get was failing, so thanks! Would be great if you could fix the formatting in your answer though as it's a little hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I use, [Dotdeb](https://dotdeb.org), an extra repository providing up-to-date all kinds of cool toys for your Debian servers like Nginx, PHP, MySQL, Redis etc.

1. Update your `sources.list`

   ```
   deb http://packages.dotdeb.org {distribution} all 
   deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org {distribution} all
   ```
2. GnuPG keys

   ```
   wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
   sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
   ```
3. Update apt & build something amazing.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

Answer (score 0):

PHP7 contains mcrypt extension internally (`source-path/ext/mcrypt/`). 
But it depends on Libmcrypt soft.

**Step 1.**

Download libmcrypt-x.x.tar.gz from http://mcrypt.sourceforge.net/
and build it.

```
cd libmcrypt-x.x
./configure
make
make install
```

**Step 2.**

Rebuild PHP7 from source and add `--with-mcrypt` option.

```
./configure ... --with-mcrypt
```

**Other way without rebuilding PHP7**

```
cd php7-source-path/ext/mcrypt/
/php7-path/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/php7-path/bin/php-config
make && make install
echo "extension=mcrypt.so" >> /php7-path/ext/php.ini
```

Restart php