# LAMP mcrypt extension

Tags: php, linux

I am using PHP version 7.0.13
I have already installed the `mcrypt` package successfully.

```
$mcrypt -v
Mcrypt v.0.9.9 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Linked against libmcrypt v.2.5.8
Copyright (C) 1998-2002 Nikos Mavroyanopoulos (nmav@gnutls.org)
```

and also

```
$php -m
[PHP Modules]
...
mcrypt
pcre
...
```

But when I use `phpinfo()` to check, the webpage dosen't show `mcrypt` information and the browser returns the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_list_modes()
```

if I call the function.

Is there any one can help me with this?

Comment: If you look at the docs for *any* mcryopt function you will see a prominent red box that says "Warning: This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.5.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0. " so switch your code to OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible to use mycrypt functions in PHP 7, though it definitely has indeed been deprecated.

This answer may help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35421763/5302315

The instructions are ubuntu-centric, but you should be able to work out the solution relatively simply if you're on another platform.

Answer (score 0):

> the webpage dosen't show mcrypt information

The PHP running inside your webserver and the PHP running from the command line share a lot of files - but not all. They may have been compiled to use different config files / different extension directories. Start by checking the location for the ini file reported by `php -i` at the command line and `phpinfo()` in a php generated web page.