# mcrypt is not loading (even after installing)

Tags: php, macos, apache, server

I have changed mac's builtin version 5.6 of php to 7.0 which works fine but my `mcrypt` is not working. I have installed it using `brew install mcrypt php70-mcrypt`. 
How I can fix this issue? I am using MacOS Sierra.

Comment: does it say mcrypt installed successfully? isnt the command: `brew install php7.0-mcrypt`? It could be possible that brew hasn't enabled the extension. see this guys answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35421763/6208463

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you restarted PHP. Then, at the command line, type php -v and make sure you're actually using 7.0.

If it still doesn't work make a php file and run phpinfo() and see if the extension is loading. If not, please provide any further information you can.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on the `mcrypt` after installing it? You can use the following command to activate the `mcrypt`.

**PHP5**

```
php5enmod mcrypt
```

**PHP7+**

```
phpenmod mcrypt
```

Also, You can do this by uncommenting the line for `mcrypt` in `php.ini`.
Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the extension by editing /etc/php.ini. If this file is not present, copy /etc/php.ini.default and rename it:

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

Edit the /etc/php.ini file and add the following:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

and Restart apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```