# How do I integrate SagePay in WordPress

Tags: integration, opayo

Basically I want to integrate SagePay in WordPress.

I have tried to integrate following the guideline in the documentation provided by SagePay. But I received the Following error.

**Ooops!!!**
Setup error: 
mcrypt not loaded.

Please refer to Readme.html document for proper setup.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to install or enable mcrypt. See here:-

[mcrypt is not loading (even after installing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361239/mcrypt-is-not-loading-even-after-installing)