# Deploy Laravel with GitlabCI failed on mcrypt extension

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-4, mcrypt

I would like to deploy my Laravel project with GitLabCI and docker. I have a yaml file with the following `before_script`:

`docker-php-ext-install mbstring mcrypt pdo_mysql curl json intl gd xml zip bz2 opcache`

Its return with this:

```
error: /usr/src/php/ext/mcrypt does not exist

usage: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install [-jN] ext-name [ext-name ...]
   ie: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install gd mysqli
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install -j5 gd mbstring mysqli pdo pdo_mysql shmop

if custom ./configure arguments are necessary, see docker-php-ext-configure

Possible values for ext-name:
bcmath bz2 calendar ctype curl dba dom enchant exif fileinfo filter ftp gd gettext gmp hash iconv imap interbase intl json ldap mbstring mysqli oci8 odbc opcache pcntl pdo pdo_dblib pdo_firebird pdo_mysql pdo_oci pdo_odbc pdo_pgsql pdo_sqlite pgsql phar posix pspell readline recode reflection session shmop simplexml snmp soap sockets sodium spl standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tidy tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlrpc xmlwriter xsl zend_test zip

Some of the above modules are already compiled into PHP; please check
the output of "php -i" to see which modules are already loaded.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I tried to install manually the mcrypt with apt-get install following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083470/php7-laravel-mcrypt-issue) answers, but nothing worked for me. Cheked [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/laravel-ci-testing-with-gitlab) forum post too, but there is no mentioned about this error.

gitlab-ci.yaml file:

```
before_script:
  # Update packages 
  - apt-get update -yqq

  - apt-get install -my wget gnupg
  # Upgrade to Node 7
  - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash -

  # Install dependencies
  - apt-get install bzip2 git nodejs libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt-dev libvpx-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev libldap2-dev unixodbc-dev libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libaspell-dev libsnmp-dev libpcre3-dev libtidy-dev -yqq

  # Install php extensions
  - docker-php-ext-install mbstring pdo_mysql curl json intl gd xml zip bz2 opcache

  # Install Node dependencies.
  # comment this out if you don't have a node dependency
  - npm install
  - npm install -g bower
  - npm install -g gulp-cli

  # Install Composer and project dependencies.
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  - php composer.phar install
```

Using php7.0 and Laravel 5.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue. Mcrypt was deprecated in PHP 7.2. Here's how to get around it now:

```
  image: php:7.2

  before_script:
    # Update packages
    - apt-get update -yqq

    # Install dependencies
    - apt-get install git libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt-dev libvpx-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev libldap2-dev unixodbc-dev libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libaspell-dev libsnmp-dev libpcre3-dev libtidy-dev -yqq

    # Install php extensions
    - docker-php-ext-install mbstring pdo_mysql curl json intl gd xml zip bz2 opcache pcntl

    ....    

    # PHP 7.2 Mcrypt & pcntl
    - pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
    - docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

    ....
```

Comment: I will try it. Thanks

Comment: Please mark as solved if it indeed solved your issue.