# Install Mcrypt library to google cloud

Tags: codeigniter, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, php-7, mcrypt

I am using google cloud compute engine for hosting my site.

I am using php 7.0.2 and codeigniter 3.1.7

and i am getting bellow error

```
`The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension.`
```

To install Mcrypt library i used bellow code.

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.0-mcrypt
```

And then restarted the instance.

But still getting same error.

Comment: use Sodium or OpenSSL?  http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php

Comment: Also, are you getting errors from the apt-get install?

Comment: You might also need to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083470/php7-laravel-mcrypt-issue#answer-35421763) answer in the discussion thread, where PHP7 was missing mcrypt module. see if that helps you